# Questions about the constant sheaf.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ an Abelian group. The constant sheaf $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$ determined by $A$ is defined as follows. Give $A$ the discrete topology and for any open set $U \subseteq X$, let $\mathcal{A}(U)$ be the ggroup of all continuous maps of $U$ into $A$. My question is why for any connected open set $U$, $\mathcal{A}(U) \cong A$? I think that since $A$ has the discrete topology, single points of $A$ are open. So the preimage $V$ of a point of $A$ under a contineous map $f$ is an open subset of $U$. Since $U$ is connected, $V=U$. Therefore every contineous map is determined by a point of $A$. Therefore $\mathcal{A}(U) \cong A$. Is this true? Thank you very much.

Comment: $\mathcal A(U)$ is certainly in bijective correspondence with $A$ by your argument, but you still have to show that this correspondence is a homomorphism of abelian groups.

Comment: Your question is simply: «why is a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ from a connected topologcal space to a discrete topological space necessarily constant?» There is no need to get sheaves involved.